# angular js to map very large amount of data

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to map and display like 5000-6000 amount of data. I receive a set of IDs from first call and than based on that call a second one to get the displayable name passing the IDs. My service looks like this

```
.factory('getDisplayName', function($http, $q){
   var deffered = $q.defer();
   return{
       getName: function(ids){    //array
             $http.get(url+ids)
                    .success(function(data){
                        deffered.resolve({
                           dname: _.map(data, function(d){
                                        return d.groupId+":"+d.display_name;
                                    })
                        });
                    }).error(function(err){
                        deffered.reject(err);
                        console.log("error in getting display names");
                    });
                return deffered.promise;
       }
    };
    });

getDisplayName.getName([1,2.....6000]).then(function(d){
     $scope.displayList = d.dname;
    });
```

html:

```
   <div ng-repeat="name in displayList">{{name}}</div>
```

But I face a problem this approach is not enough to display ids without blocking the UI. UI get block.

I am trying to find a better way to handle large amount of data without blocking the UI . 
thanks! in advance for any suggestions

Comment: What about a pagination? Do you really need to show all 6000 at once?

Comment: this is a known issue with angular, search for "angularjs performance tuning" tips.  here some good article I found: http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/, http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

Comment: @gearsdigital yes that is the issue no pagination allowed (since have to show them at once). this is performance test we are doing at our app .

Comment: @aarosil thanks for the pointer to articles.

Comment: You should consider to extend the `ng-repeat` directive with `track by`. `ng-repeat="name in displayList track by $index"`

Comment: @gearsdigital thanks for the tip but already tried "track by " but seems like ng-repeat have some bottleneck

Comment: Use server side pagination.

Comment: @zsong thats is some 3rd party API and I have no control on how it work ...

Comment: @user429035 Call that API in your server side and cache the data, and then return sliced data to your UI.

Comment: Another options is to load up all of the data on the front-end and have all the paging happening on the front-end

Comment: thanks!  @EstebanFelix.. i will try solve with one of the solution you guys suggested.

Comment: thanks @zsong will try out on of the solution